# Git-flow hotfix merging to develop being ahead produces XX commits ahead

Tags: git, git-flow

How to reproduce:

1. Develop is 6 commits ahead master.
2. Create hotfix branch from master.
3. Make 2 commits to on hotfix.
4. Finish hotfix branch (merge to master, tag, merge to develop)
5. Master is now 3 ahead origin/master (2 commits+merge commit)
6. Develop is 57 ahead origin/develop (WHAT?!)

Why isn't local devleop 3 ahead origin/develop? I have a feeling it has to do with the --no-ff flag in the merges...

Comment: Are you doing this in github?

Comment: Yes @GuillemoMansilla

Comment: Are you manually merging those branches? or are you actually opening a pull request?

Comment: Manually merging @GuillemoMansilla

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation once. Since I had write access to the main repo I was doing the merge operations directly to upstream. That would cause some problems. 
So instead of doing the merge manually you must do it through a pull request, that is, push your Hotfix branch to your origin (your fork) then create a pull request from hotfix to master, after accepting the pull request the hotfix branch will be merged to master.

Now just open a pull request from master to develop.

Comment: I merged to my local develop. Then it says local develop is 57 ahead remote develop...

Comment: are you doing all these merges through a pull request?

Comment: then you're not following my instructions